# How can I plot legends on only some of my curves that all plotted together?

Tags: plotting, legending

I am using ListPlot to plot many lines in the same graph. I want to put in a legend but only for a subset of these lines. For example

```
ListPlot[{P1,P2,P3,P4},PlotLegend -> {"a","b"}]
```

where P1,P2,P3,P4 are some lists that one can plot, however this creates a legend for -all- plots P1,...,P4, with empty texts for some of them. How can I make a legend that only lables two of the lines?

Comment: Perhaps Show[{ListPlot[{P1,P2}, PlotLegend->{"a", "b"}], ListPlot[{P3,P4}]}] including PlotRange if needed.

Comment: You mean `PlotLegends`, not `PlotLegend`.

Comment: @Verbeia: He may really be using the old PlotLegends package -- it had the syntax and behavior described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me

```
{p1, p2, p3, p4} = 
 Accumulate /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {4, 50}];


ListLinePlot[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, PlotLegends -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

What version of Mathematica are you using?

`ListPlot` works fine, though of course by default you get dots not an unbroken line.

Comment: Same result for v9

Comment: Actually I was using PlotLegend, which gives the behaviour I described (and no error message). With PlotLegends it works fine now.

Comment: But what is the syntax if he only wanted to label, for example, P1 and P4? Without using the Show function..

Comment: This is trivial. What if one wants to have the legends just for e.g. P1 and P4?